# Athena CSV: Issues with trailing slashes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a csv file as follows

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
1,"She said ""Hi!""",3
1,2\,3
1,"2,0\",3
```

and an Athena table created as follows

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `david_korean_test`(
`a` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
`b` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
`c` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
'escapeChar'='\"', 
'quoteChar'='\"', 
'separatorChar'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
's3://...'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

The first 2 rows display fine but slashes cause issues with rows 3 and 4

In row 3 column b just has `2` while in row 4 columns b and c are empty.

Is there a setting that can help with this or is it a known issue?

Comment: Why do you have these backslashes in your files? How would you like the system to interpret `2\` and `2,0\`? A backslash normally means "Ignore any special meaning associated with the next character", which means Line 3 is missing a third column and Line 4 is missing a closing quote. You can certainly change the `escapeChar` to something else, but it would be better to avoid such characters from getting into your data.

Comment: The escape character is set to double quotes, I would have assumed then that escape would hold no special meaning? The backslashes arrive in customer data, I can remove them but would prefer not to

Comment: The data you are receiving is _not_ in CSV format. From your example, the backslashes serve no purpose and, if anything, need to be totally ignored by Athena. However, there is no property that can tell it to ignore characters while loading. At best, you can tell Athena to _not_ treat backslahes as Escape characters, but then the backslashes will be included in the data, making it impossible to treat number fields as numbers. Your best option would be to remove those characters from the files via pre-processing.